# Android: for-loop gives reversed values

Tags: android, loops, nested, reverse

I´m trying to set up a calendar with day objects (from my day class). If the loop reaches the next month, it steps into another for-loop with other conditions. These conditions don´t seem to be right, because the inner loop gives me back the days in a reverse order and i can´t figure out whats wrong.

This is the complete code of the activity (see listOfDays() Method where the loop is):

```
package com.mobilecartography.tudresdenspeechorganiser;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;

import com.mobilecartography.tudresdenspeechorganiser.R;
import com.mobilecartography.tudresdenspeechorganiser.DatabaseHelper;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    
  ArrayList<CurrentDay> currentweek = new ArrayList<CurrentDay>();
  
  SQLiteDatabase database = null;
  Cursor dbCursor;
  DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    try {
        setListofDays();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ExpandableListView listView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    MyExpandableListAdapter adapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(this,
        currentweek);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
  
  
  
//fill list with 8 entrys with dates (based on joda time and java.util.date) for the next 8 days, for 
//each days query presentations for that specific day from sql database  
  public void setListofDays() throws ParseException {
      DateTime cal = new DateTime();    //jodatime calendar for todays date
      CurrentDay day = null;
      int maxDay = cal.dayOfMonth().getMaximumValue();
      int currentday = cal.getDayOfMonth();
      int currentmonth; 
      int currentyear = cal.getYear();
      
      for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        //check if day of iteration is already in the next month
        if (currentday+i > maxDay){  
            
            for (int h = 0; h < 20 - i; h++){       
                
                    currentmonth = cal.getMonthOfYear()+1;
                    
                    // get name of day of week from 2nd calendar
                    String dateString = String.format("%d-%d-%d", currentyear, currentmonth, h);
                    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(dateString);
                    String dayofweek = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.GERMAN).format(date);
                    
                    day = new CurrentDay(1+h, dayofweek, currentmonth, currentyear);
                    }
                }           
        else {
            currentmonth = cal.getMonthOfYear();
            
            // get name of day of week from 2nd calendar
            String dateString = String.format("%d-%d-%d", currentyear, currentmonth, currentday+i);
            Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(dateString);
            String dayofweek = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.GERMAN).format(date);
            
            day = new CurrentDay(currentday+i, dayofweek, currentmonth, currentyear);
        }

        //reference dbHelper instances of mainactivity and currentday object
        day.dbHelper = this.dbHelper;
          
        //load presentations that take place on that day
        try {
            day.loadPresentations();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        currentweek.add(day);       //add day object to list of days
        }
    }
}
```

This is the currentday class:

```
    package com.mobilecartography.tudresdenspeechorganiser;

//This class is used for creating day objects with attached data from an sql database
//that are used in the calendar of the main activity

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import com.mobilecartography.tudresdenspeechorganiser.DatabaseHelper;

public class CurrentDay {

    public int day;
    public int month;
    public int year;
    public String dayofweek;
    DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    public List<String> children;
    SQLiteDatabase database = null;
    Cursor dbCursor;
    
    //constructor for day object which consists out of a day, the name of the weekday, the month and the year
    public CurrentDay(int day, String dayofweek, int month, int year) {
        this.day = day;
        this.month = month;
        this.year = year;
        this.dayofweek = dayofweek;
    }

    //query titles of the presentations from sql database for specific date
    public void loadPresentations() {
        
            try {
                dbHelper.createDataBase();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
        }
        
        try {
            //get date from day object and transfrom it into sql date
            SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");  
            java.util.Date parsedUtilDate;
            String date_string = this.year+"-"+this.month+"-"+this.day;
            parsedUtilDate = formater.parse(date_string);
            java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(parsedUtilDate.getTime());  
            
            children = new ArrayList<String>();
        
            database = dbHelper.getDataBase();
            
            //get titles of table if they have the date of the day object
            dbCursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT Titel FROM presentations WHERE Datum = '" +sqlDate +"'",
                    null);

            dbCursor.moveToFirst();
            int index = dbCursor.getColumnIndex("Titel");
            while (!dbCursor.isAfterLast()) {
                String record = dbCursor.getString(index);
                children.add(record);
                dbCursor.moveToNext();
            }
            
        } 
            catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
        finally {
            if (database != null) {
                dbHelper.close();
            }
        }
    }

    //get description of day object as shown in child view of expandable list
    public String getName() {
        return this.dayofweek+", "+Integer.toString(this.day)+"."+Integer.toString(this.month)+".";
    }
      

}
```

so instead of count up 1+h counts backwards:

> how its supposed to be: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
>
> how its displayed: 8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1

I´m quite a beginner with android and programming and i guess there are better ways to create a calendarlist, but i just want to know whats wrong here so where is my mistake?

Comment: What is `day` and `CurrentDay`?

Comment: a class object defined in the CurrentDay Class: `public CurrentDay(int day, String dayofweek, int month, int year)`. The last three values are ok, but the first one (int day) isn´t.

Comment: there must be anywhere another issue, maybe, can You please post the full code?

Comment: ...I think we also need to see CurrentDay class

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with Your nested loop....I think the problem here is, that if the first loop starts for example with i is 1, it will subbed from h, then the second loop starts. But if day is the only integer here and You are doing nothing with it until the second loop is over, only the last iteration through this loop will give You a value.

Comment: i´ve posted the rest of the code. Just a basic questionof understanding: As soon as the if statement is true, the code jumps into the inner loop with h as it´s variable. And the i doesn´t change any more until the h-loop hast finished, right? And when the h-loop has finished, the if-statement is fullfilled, which means that also the outer loop with variable i should be closed and the code should continue in the line `day.dbHelper = this.dbHelper;`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i´ve found the problem:
i added the addDay() and loadPresentations() Methods to the end of the h-loop and additionally added a break at the end of the for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        //check if day of iteration is already in the next month
        if (currentday+i > maxDay){  

            for (int h = 1; h < 20-i; h++){     
                    currentmonth = cal.getMonthOfYear()+1;

                    // get name of day of week
                    String dateString = String.format("%d-%d-%d", currentyear, currentmonth, h);
                    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(dateString);
                    String dayofweek = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.GERMAN).format(date);

                    day = new CurrentDay(h, dayofweek, currentmonth, currentyear);

                    //reference dbHelper instances of mainactivity and currentday object
                    day.dbHelper = this.dbHelper;

                    //load presentations that take place on that day
                    try {
                        day.loadPresentations();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    currentweek.add(day);       //add day object with attached presentations to list of days
                    }
                }           
        else {
            currentmonth = cal.getMonthOfYear();

            // get name of day of week
            String dateString = String.format("%d-%d-%d", currentyear, currentmonth, currentday+i);
            Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(dateString);
            String dayofweek = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.GERMAN).format(date);

            day = new CurrentDay(currentday+i, dayofweek, currentmonth, currentyear);

            //reference dbHelper instances of mainactivity and currentday object
            day.dbHelper = this.dbHelper;

            //load presentations that take place on that day
            try {
                day.loadPresentations();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            currentweek.add(day); //add day object with attached presentations to list of days
            }

        if (currentday+i > maxDay){
                break;
            }
        }
```